# Error in installing app on android studio

Tags: android

I'm getting an error while installing apps on my redmi 2 prime.
I am using windows 10.
Apps is not installing even after the pop-up in my phone.
 See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRGeQ.png) for futher details.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please paste the error (using SO's code formatting). Because of the absense of details, your question as it currently is will probably not receive a good answer, and may be closed. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If It's the case happens with many then it's a common thing in Xiaomi's phones.

Here's what you should do:
Go to developer options (Settings-Additional settings-Developer options).
Swipe to the last option at the bottom.
Disable MIUI customization and restart your phone.
Additionally, you can disable verify apps over ADB.